# Exam class: alignement problem with minipage environment containing text and image

Tags: horizontal-alignment, minipage, exam

I cannot figure out how to solve this issue. As a MWE

```
\documentclass[11pt,addpoints,a4paper]{exam}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[a4paper,left=1cm,right=1cm,top=1.5cm,bottom=1cm,footskip=0.1cm
]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}  
\usepackage{graphicx}

\footer{}{\thepage}{}

\begin{document}

\begin{questions}
\question[30] \lipsum[1]
\question[20] \lipsum[2]
\question[50] \begin{minipage}[t]{0.55\textwidth}{\vspace{0pt}}
\lipsum[3]
\end{minipage}\hfill
 \begin{minipage}[t]{0.4\textwidth}{\vspace {0pt}}
\includegraphics[width=0.95\textwidth]{example-image-a.png}
\end{minipage}
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moving the third question inside the minipage environmnet and changing some lengths we get:

```
\documentclass[11pt,addpoints,a4paper]{exam}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage[a4paper,left=1cm,right=1cm,top=1.5cm,bottom=1cm,footskip=0.1cm
]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}  
\usepackage{graphicx}

\footer{}{\thepage}{}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{questions}
        \question[30] \lipsum[1]
        \question[20] \lipsum[2]
        
        \begin{minipage}[t]{0.6\textwidth}{\vspace{0pt}}
            \question [50]\lipsum[3]
        \end{minipage}\hfill
        \begin{minipage}[t]{0.35\textwidth}{\vspace {0pt}}
            \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a.png}
        \end{minipage}
    \end{questions}
\end{document}
```

[image]